# Response too large to return when using destination_table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to take a large ( ~9 million row ) table and create smaller tables from it via the query interface:

```
bq query --destination_table=AC25_DS.SmtpSend_ACXX_2013052000_new "select * from LOAD_STAGE_DS.smtpsend520 where accountId=XX5"
Waiting on job_8de2e91ee06d4805844b09591e43968a ... (7s) Current status: DONE    
BigQuery error in query operation: Error processing job 'messagebus.com:mbtest:job_8de2e91ee06d4805844b09591e43968a': Response too large to return.
```

One of the accounts in the table is about 95% of the total table size, so that is probably why it is blowing up, but what is the recommended method of breaking a large table up into smaller tables via the query interface.

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to create 100 shards of your table. Provided that you have some id-like field, you could select the rows where the id field has specific modulo when divided by 100. For this example you would run a 100 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ABS(HASH(id) % 100) == 0
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ABS(HASH(id) % 100) == 1
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ABS(HASH(id) % 100) == 2
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ABS(HASH(id) % 100) == 3
...
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ABS(HASH(id) % 100) == 99
```

and store the result into 100 tables each containing (roughly) 1/100 of the original table's rows.

Comment: The shards need to go into a dataset per account, which I guess could also be split up by hash to make them smaller. If there is no way to "create table as select *" without materializing the data, I can split the initial load up to smaller pieces instead of doing it post load via sql.